# Service is destroyed if called from same file, but not if object of that service is created (and called from seperate file)

Tags: java, android, service

This may be a stupid question, so please forgive me. I'm still learning java-android.
So for learning purposes I've created useless program.
1. When activity is launched it starts a simple service
2. Service registers broadcast receiver ( which listens for incoming SMS messages )
3. When SMS message arrives, service should stop itself.

Here is my code: (Service class)

```
// This is my service class. Lifecycle methods are ommited
public void finish() {
    Log.d("APP", "finish called");
    stopSelf();

}
```

Following is my broadcast receiver ( in seperate file)

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

    Log.d("APP", "SMS Received");

    new MyService().finish();
}
```

So, when message arrives onReceive is triggered. Then finish() is called and executed ( I see in my LOGCAT ), but service is never destroyed.

On the other hand if I make this way in my service class:

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    finish();


    return START_STICKY;
}
```

Then service is created and right after then destroyed. Why is working this way, and not the other way also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because in your `onReceive` method you instantiating a service instead of using existing one. So you just need a reference to your exicting service instance and then you should call `finish()` method on it.

Comment: Thank you. That did the trick: onReceive i put this code: ((MyService)context).finish();

Comment: Or is there some other way to achive this also?